# Can UDP (unicast client) recvfrom() other servers other than the one sendto()?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I am creating a UDP socket client in C (unicast) and is wondering why recvfrom()  has a struct sockaddr * argument in which in the man page says, 
A null pointer, or points to a sockaddr structure in which the sending address is to be stored.

Is it possible that I could receive a message from a different server other than the one I sendto? If yes, how to create this scenario?

If no, is it correct to say that this argument is only useful when broadcast mode is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. The reason for this is that UDP is not stream-based, but packet-based. Every packet is treated without any history (other packets sent or received).

For this reason you may also open a UDP port and then send packets to different hosts from it. However, I do not remember how well this is supported by the API.

Answer (score 0):

The UDP socket will `recvfrom()` any host sending to this one with correct port unless you explicitly `connect()`, in which case you can just `write()` and `read()`, and get errors upon received ICMP messages.

Answer (score -1):

Considering you always have two parties in UDP, it seems rather obvious that someone has to recvfrom() first.